# Can't override / extend Types in Typescript

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, typescript

I am having problems with ts compiler errors for array functions on `FileList` and `DOMStringList` Arrays.

`(83,34): error TS2339: Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'FileList'.`

I tried to override the default types in `lib.d.ts` by extending the types like this:

```
interface FileList {
  length: number;
  item(index: number): File;
  [index: number]: File;
  filter(callback: Function, thisArg?: any);
  find(callback: Function, thisArg?: any);
  findIndex(callback: Function, thisArg?: any);
  forEach(callback: Function);
  indexOf(searchElement: any, fromIndex?: any);
  push(elements: any);
  sort(compareFunction: Function);
}
declare var FileList: {
  prototype: FileList;
  new(): FileList;
};

interface DOMStringList {
  length: number;
  contains(str: string): boolean;
  item(index: number): string;
  [index: number]: string;
  filter(callback: Function, thisArg?: any);
  find(callback: Function, thisArg?: any);
  findIndex(callback: Function, thisArg?: any);
  forEach(callback: Function);
  indexOf(searchElement: any, fromIndex?: any);
  push(elements: any);
  sort(compareFunction: Function);
}

declare var DOMStringList: {
  prototype: DOMStringList;
  new(): DOMStringList;
}
```

IntelliJ correctly links to my `ts-fixes.d.ts` file and does not highlight `.forEach` as missing property.

However, the compiler still complains about the missing property `forEach` on my `FileList` Type.

Why is the compiler not using my extended interface?

Comment: That's the same way the Types are declared in the default lib: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L7916

Comment: it is if i put my extended interfaces in the same file. But not if I want to declare it globally in a separate file